# CREATE LOGIN "MUST_CHANGE" does not work for Azure

Tags: sql-server-2019, users, password, azure-sql-server

I want to create logins for users for my Azure SQL database.

Naturally I don't want to know the users' passwords so I want to set it up so that they HAVE to change their password on first login.

Normally I'd just use the `MUST_CHANGE` option for the `CREATE LOGIN` command but Azure does not allow that. I get the error `Keyword or statement option 'must_change' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.`.

So, how do I go about doing what I want to do in Azure SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp... the official statement from the Azure support team is... there is no way to do this.

The **OFFICIAL** method to add a new user to an Azure SQL Server and **NOT** know their password is as follows (I wish I was even mildly joking, these are the exact steps Azure support gave me):

- Create an additional SQL login in the master database.

`CREATE LOGIN test WITH PASSWORD = 'initial password';`

- Create a user account in the master database associated with this new login.

`CREATE USER testUSER FOR LOGIN test;`

- Add the user account to the `dbmanager`, the `loginmanager` role, or both in the master database using the ALTER ROLE statement.

`ALTER ROLE dbmanager ADD MEMBER testUSER`

`ALTER ROLE loginmanager ADD MEMBER testUSER`

On user site:

- Change their password by themselves

`ALTER LOGIN test WITH PASSWORD = 'pass';`

I, personally, do not think this is a good idea, at all but Azure have specifically set it to be this way for SQL user authentication.

Comment: You have got to be kidding.  8 months have passed since this question.  Is this really still the way that it is?

Comment: @RobertSievers, yup. Microsoft want to move things to AD authentication so I don't think they will ever bother making SQL authentication viable.